# How can I get the inherited CSS value using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to get the value of an inherited CSS property using Javascript. I haven't been able to find a comprehensive answer.

Example CSS:

```
div {
    width: 80%;
}
```

Example Markup:

```
<div id="mydiv"> Some text </div>
```

Using javascript (jQuery, or native), I need to get the width of the element-- not in pixels, but the string "80%".

```
$('#mydiv').css('width'); // returns in px
$('#mydiv')[0].style.width // empty string
getComputedStyle($('#mydiv')[0]).width // returns in px
```

The reason I need the value as a string is because I need to copy the style to another element. If it's declared as a percent, the other value needs to be a percent. If it's declared in px, the other value needs to be in px.

The real trick is that this property could be inherited, not declared explicitly on the element (as in my example).

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate [Inherited CSS Values via Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169967/inherited-css-values-via-javascript)

Comment: Not only do you have the issue if needing to get an inherited value, you also need to get a % value, which is far from simple: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131462/getting-values-of-global-stylesheet-in-jquery/7132264#7132264

Comment: @Martin : It's not quite a duplicate... I did see that answer, but I need the % value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to get the percentage value I'm afraid. You can try something like this:

```
var widthpx = getComputedStyle($('#mydiv')[0]).width;
var parentWidth = $('#mydiv').parent().css('width')

var width = ( 100 * parseFloat(widthpx) / parseFloat(parentWidth) ) + '%';
```

Comment: that it would be not possible. There are ways, even without jQuery.

Comment: Hm... not quite what I'm looking for. A co-worker actually suggested this. You're probably right in that there's no way to get the percentage, which answers my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

What you are searching for is [this quirksmode.org article](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/getstyles.html#link3). It proposes the function

```
function getStyle(el, styleProp)    {
    var x = document.getElementById(el);
    if (x.currentStyle)
        var y = x.currentStyle[styleProp];
    else if (window.getComputedStyle)
        var y = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(x,null).getPropertyValue(styleProp);
    return y;
}
```

Still, you should read that article carefully. They names of the `styleProp`s are not really cross-browser, and you will see how different browsers handle this. Opera seems to have the best support for reporting the correct values.

Comment: This is a library, and it doesn't officially support the latest browser versions.

Comment: I cant see why one example function would be a library?

Comment: I suppose it isn't, it just appeared to be. Why not just post the code snippet in your answer instead of linking to it? Then I'll remove my downvote.

Comment: Because the article describes the pitfalls of the snippet. Also, it may get updated - my post won't. I think it would be better to link to the origin, than spread unmaintained, source-less code snippets :)

Comment: @Bergi I've been over that article. It was tough to follow, and you & the article both mentioned there are problems with the method being not cross-browser compatible. Thanks for the help, though!

Comment: yeah, but for a simple "width" it will work. You may get into trouble with shorthand properties (border, background) or CSS vs. JS property names.

Answer (score 0):

get the offSetWidth of the element, and the offsetWidth of its offsetParent, and calculate the percentage from the two integers.

Answer (score 0):

This binds an event handler to an element for the `click` event and alerts the element's relative width compared to it's parent element.

```
​$('#mydiv').on('click', function () {

    //element width divided by parent width times 100 to make a percentage
    alert(Math.round($(this).width() / $(this).parent().width() * 100) + '%');
});​​​​​​​​​​
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/X67p5/