# is there a way to reference a child node and get say an inherited background color?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was doing some initial testing in jsFiddle as follows: https://jsfiddle.net/6pqxfy2o/

```js
$(function(){
 console.log("fired");
  $("div").each(function(){
   console.log($(this).attr("class"));
    console.log($(this).css("background-color"))})
})
```

```css
.color{
  background-color:teal;
}

.dim{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.sub-dim{
  width: 50px;
  height:50px;
  border: solid 1px white;
}
.ping {
  background-color: cyan;
}

.ack {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dim color">
  <div class="sub-dim ack">
  
  </div>
  <div class="sub-dim ping">
  
  </div>
  <div class="sub-dim">
  
  </div>
</div>
```

This was showing that when running, it did not actually pass the inherited color into the child.

I am curious though how I can get the `background color` of the `sub-dim` which has no background color, such as:  current `background-color` or nearest.

My end goal would be to say:  When iterating over `sub-dim` to return [red, cyan,teal] or color codes.  Based on the item I gave you, the div is transparent and the parent's color is showing through.

Comment: Maybe this would help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9729864/how-can-i-get-the-inherited-css-value-using-javascript

Comment: Could you not simply get the parent colour?

Comment: Your question is incoherent: `sub-dim` **IS** transparent, so there is **NO** background-color. If you want the color of the element behind shining through, you could not compute it, since you can have anything behind. If you want the background-color of the parent, you can do it.

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't see the problem. You have the background color for <div class="sub-dim">. It is rgba(0, 0, 0, 0). What do you mean by: "it did not actually pass the inherited color into the child"?

Comment: my end goal was to get the color shining through i guess.  yeam i realized there is no background color, but i was not sure the best approach to get the color which is under neath.   I was thinking to do it programatically, but i was not sure if there was a css property or something i could leverage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the color is transparent, you can just set it to `inherit` and get the new computed color.

```js
// Some browsers say "transparent" and some "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)"
var transparent = (function() {
  var backup = document.body.style.backgroundColor;
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
  var bg = getComputedStyle(document.body).backgroundColor;
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = backup;
  return bg;
})();
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName("div"), function(el) {
  var bg = getComputedStyle(el).backgroundColor;
  if (bg === transparent) {
    var backup = el.style.backgroundColor;
    el.style.backgroundColor = 'inherit';
    bg = getComputedStyle(el).backgroundColor;
    el.style.backgroundColor = backup;
  }
  console.log(el.className, ":", bg);
});
```

```css
.color {
  background-color: teal;
}
.dim {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.sub-dim {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: solid 1px white;
}
.ping {
  background-color: cyan;
}
.ack {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="dim color">
  <div class="sub-dim ack"></div>
  <div class="sub-dim ping"></div>
  <div class="sub-dim"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: perfect answer.  Thank you. :)  I was curious maybe this is a different question, but are you able to inherit classes as well?

Comment: Will probably need to add in a check against `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)` too as `backgroundColor` will hold the rgb/a value and not the `"transparent"` value on some browsers

Comment: @PatrickEvans Yes, the difference in computed colors is so annoying

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understand the problem, but you could try

```
.sub-dim.ack {
  background-color: red;
}
```

or

```
.ack, .ack * {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Obviosly try to be ore specific with which child elements you'd like to target.

This would likely be a lot easier in SASS.