# JavaScript dir method returns empty string for text direction

Tags: javascript, text, bidirectional

This returns an empty string when I try to determine the default text direction...

```
alert(document.getElementById('example').dir);
```

I would like to determine if the default text direction is ltr or rtl.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169967/inherited-css-values-via-javascript to access inherited style.

Comment: Do not edit my posts, if you disagree comment first; all edits have only diluted the detail and meaning of my questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I alert during debugging, like so:

```
alert(window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('editor_rich')).direction);
```

Answer (score 4):

ltr/rtl is defined with the css "direction" property. It can also be defined using the "dir" attribute on the element in the DOM.

If you're checking for the attribute value, use the getAttribute method:

```
 document.getElementById('example').getAttribute('dir');
```

Also, check the style of the element. It defaults to ltr so if undefined, should return as an empty string. Otherwise it should say "rtl"

```
 document.getElementById('example').style.direction;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/direction

Answer (score 3):

I'd use

```
var elm = document.getElementById('example') || document.body;
return window.getComputedStyle(elm).direction;
```

Comment: Using alert(window.getComputedStyle(elm).direction);, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if it is blank that means it isn't specified in your element's `dir` attribute.