# Why does getComputedStyle not return display:none for an element hidden by a parent?

Tags: javascript, html, css, inheritance, dom

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1169967/798371) page and the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4866229/798371), the right way to get inherited CSS values via Javascript is [`getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle).  However, that does not work in the following example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
    <form id="iterateThroughMe">
        <div class="notHidden"><input name="myNum" type="number" /></div>
        <div><input name="myOtherNum" type="number" /></div>
        <input name="myText" type="text" />
        <div id="hider" style="display: none;">
            <input name="hiddenElement" type="number" />
        </div>
    </form>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var inputs = $("#iterateThroughMe").find('input');
    for(var i = 0; i<inputs.length; i++) {
        var displayStyle = window.getComputedStyle(inputs[i], null).display;
        console.log(
            (($(inputs[i]).is(":hidden"))?"in":"")+
            "visible element: ",inputs[i],"has display style",displayStyle);
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Saved and opened in a browser, the following is visible on the console:

```
visible element:  <input name=​"myNum" type=​"number">​ has display style inline-block
visible element:  <input name=​"myOtherNum" type=​"number">​ has display style inline-block
visible element:  <input name=​"myText" type=​"text">​ has display style inline-block
invisible element:  <input name=​"hiddenElement" type=​"number">​ has display style inline-block
```

There is a specific way to access hidden/visible status in jQuery, noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/178450/798371), which works in the example above but is [not always appropriate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866229/check-element-css-display-with-javascript#comment5408516_4866277).  Why does getComputedStyle not distinguish between hidden and non-hidden elements, producing `inline-block` on all four lines instead of `none` at the end of the output?

Answer (score 5):

The element isn't rendered because it is contained within something that is `display: none`, **not** because it has *inherited* the value `none` for that property.